# Router internet light is off but blinks while it's starting up

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I got a new dlink 816 ac750 router. My ISP has not yet reset my MAC ID so unfortunately I am unable to use internet over it.

But I am facing a strange problem. The issues are listed.

- When I turn on the router without anything connected to "Internet" port in it, The light turns green as soon as it starts up but then goes off when the router begins to broadcast the signal. This is normal.
- When I put my ISP CAT6 cable in the port, it blinks while starting up but then again goes off when the router is ready. This can be an ISP issue. However, the same cable when used with my old router works in a normal fashion.
- When I put a LAN cable in the internet port and connect it to my laptop's Ethernet port similar thing as above happens. But I get a "Limited Access" connection over my laptop's ethernet.

In both the cases above when the cable is connected to the router, it shows as "PPPOE connected" in the router's status page in browser. I am just confused, why the internet LED light doesn't turn on? Will it be a firmware issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a PPPoE connection. You would most likely need to set up this type of connection in your new router. Generally the Cable Modem would automatically dial in your connection. But it appears it doesn't. So, your router might need to be configured to log into your ISP's connection, since PPPoE supports having to have credentials to use it with a username and password and some routers are capable of auto-dialing for your computers for you. Anyways, it appears the modem doesn't do it from what you are saying, so it means you have to manually configure it in the routers settings and it will most likely require a username and password for the connection as well, which your ISP has that info, and you can give them a call for it, if you don't know what it is.

But it could also be your ISP. As you did say they haven't updated your Mac ID. It isn't common for ISP's that use cable modems to use a access control list that uses your devices mac address anymore rather they just track their own hardware on their line to prevent you from using unauthorized modems.

You do have a modem. Its just called a cable modem instead of a DSL modem. Pretty much both work exactly the same way, just communicate with the ISP over different cables and protocols. Anyways as for the lights, the reason your light stays on in two of your scenarios and then turns off, is possibly the modem recognizing the credentials as being valid because it was able to log into the ISP's network, but on the ISP's end it returns a message to the modem connection not authorized possibly because it believes the device isn't allowed based on mac address id. For the other scenario, it means bad credentials and therefore it couldn't log into the ISP's network to do anything and since that is faster response then waiting on the ISP's network to determine authorization to use the network. The light immediately turns off.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But shouldn't the light atleast stay on even though it is not authorised?

Comment: Also I don't have a modem, this is a cable internet

Comment: @SanketR updated my answer, to answer your comments and revised my answer to be more specific of the cable modem and not dsl modem.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. I will wait for my ISP's staff to assist me more with this. I will accept your answer for now. Have a nice day.

Comment: I hope your ISP helps you get your modem back into working order. As for the lights, I have always been told, the internet light only stays on if there is active internet. I have been told this by a couple different ISP's that I have had when I questioned about the lights. However, that doesn't mean all modems are the same nor do all ISP's have them configured to indicate the same thing either.